# Tableau tooltip incorrect when toggling through quick filter

Tags: filter, latitude-longitude, tableau-api

Link to [workbook on public tableau](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/NumericBusinessRatings/Map)

I created calculated value to determine grade for business, and this is colormap (in tab [`Grade per Location`](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/NumericBusinessRatings/Map))

[image]

And when I hover over datapoints on map (tab [`Map`](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/NumericBusinessRatings/Map)), it displays correct Grade, i.e. `D` for `Shish Boom Bah Car Wash`

[image]

But as soon as I select **any** location from a drop-down, all grades are `A`

[image]

Tot_Avg is calculated like this:

```
{ EXCLUDE [Location (Loc)] : AVG([Rating]) }
```

Avg_Rating like this:

```
AVG([Rating])
```

And here are the conditions for receiving an A:

```
IF [Avg_Rating]  > ATTR([Tot_Avg]) - (.10 * ATTR([Tot_Avg]))
THEN "A"
```

How to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your confusion is in what that `EXCLUDE` is doing. It is NOT ignoring filters. It's just saying not to group by Location when aggregating `AVG([Rating])`. When you filter out all but one location, `AVG([Rating])` and `{ EXCLUDE [Location (Loc)] : AVG([Rating]) }` become equivalent, because with either calculation, you're averaging for all points in your filtered partition.

As a result, your condition for receiving an A will always be true if there's only one location. (Check the math: `X > X - .1X` → `X > .9X`)

Here's a different way to get what you're after. Make a calculated field (I'll call it Location Filter):

```
LOOKUP(ATTR([Location (Loc)]),0)
```

Then trash your Location filter and replace it with that field. We're doing something sneaky here - we're making the exact same filter as we had before, but we're disguising it as a table calculation (by using `LOOKUP()`). Tableau doesn't execute table calculations until after it's created the filtered partition, so we've tricked it into letting us use every location while still just examining one.