# Tableau dashboard action unresponsive

Tags: filter, action, dashboard, tableau-api

Workbook is on [Public Tableau](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/NumericBusinessRatings/BusinessDashboard)

I'm using one drop-down, which is a calculated value (refer [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466232/tableau-tooltip-incorrect-when-toggling-through-quick-filter)) to control map, and two worksheets.

When I toggle through the filter, only the relevant location appears on map, while the other two worsheets do not change, i.e. they show all locations.

[image]

How to fix this?

Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't filter multiple worksheets with a table calculation (your intuition about why is exactly right). BUT we can do something sneaky again.

First, create a parameter to replace your quick filter. Let's call it "Choose Location". Make the data type "String", then select "List" from Allowable Values. Go to "Add from Field" and select "Location (Loc)". Your parameter will now allow you to select from a list of all the different values of [Location (Loc)].

Since you want to be able to show all of the locations at once, also add "All Locations" to the parameter's list of allowable values (I put it at the top of the list because that's what my heart said to do).

Next, create a calculated field. Let's call it "Choose Location Filter".

```
IIF([Choose Location] = "All Locations", TRUE, [Choose Location] = [Location Filter])
```

This statement will return TRUE if the Location on the given row of the partition is equal to the Location selected in the parameter and FALSE otherwise. If you've selected "Multiple Locations", it will return TRUE for all rows. Note that we're still using the [Location Filter] that you made so that we can maintain all locations in our partition and calculate that Grade.

Now, in every worksheet, replace the [Location Filter] in your filter card with the [Choose Location Filter] field. Filter out the FALSEs, leaving only the TRUEs. Place the parameter control on your dashboard and use that to filter instead of the quick filter you built previously.

Comment: I tried these steps, and result is same as before, except I can only select one from the list, and each datapoint appears as green dot on map, rather than size-and-color weighted, https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/NumericBusinessRatings/BusinessDashboard

Comment: Due to work constraints, will attempt to update backend database to include static value for Grade. If you were able to figure a Tablea solution, please let me know, otherwise it's ok.

Comment: Your answer certainly helps!

Comment: The size/color issue was present in your previous solution. When you start filtering things out, the scale will automatically adjust to the max and min of the continuous variable that controls it. One solution would be to go into the color/size menu and make the start and end points static, but you'd have to do that manually. Another option would be to replace the color scale with Grade so that it's a discrete variable, but the same wouldn't work for size.

Answer (score 2):

To get tableau Action revealed on another data.

Step1

Go to Dashboard > Click on icon dashboard > Click on Action > Select Add Action > Filter and follow further steps as per given as

[image]

Step2

Click ok in action and you will get desired results

Step3

In your Dashboard Filter which is

[image]

select the icon and follow steps further which is describe below :

[image]

This will get desired results as per your requirement.

Result: your result will look like this example as given as

[image]